# CellEditing plugin - input type password

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

My grid uses the plugin `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing`.

My columns are generated dynamically in relation to my data.

The grid looks like this:

```
  ...
  columns: [],
  plugins: [
     Ext.create( 'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
        listeners: {
           beforeedit: function( oEditor, oOptions ) { ... }
           edit: function( oEditor, oOptions ) { ... }
        }
     } )
  ...
```

I am now trying to change the input field type from `text` to `password` of a single row, where there is a value `pass` in column `key`.

```
| Key   |  Value  |
__________________|
|  id   |   5     |
| user  |  admin  |
| pass  |  ****   |  <-- this cell should be input type password
___________________
```

What I tried:

Changing the input type via `Ext.get( 'textfield-1160-inputEl' ).dom.type = 'password';` in listeners `beforeedit` fails since it is not yet rendered.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom field to use in the grid:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.PasswordField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    alias: 'widget.passwordfield',
    inputType: 'password',
});
```

Which you set as `xtype` in grid:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'passwordfield',
    allowBlank: false,
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jvtjS/